# google.loader.ClientLocation: What does it return for "region" for US users?

Tags: ajax, google-api, loader

I can't seem to find this info anywhere: When you get geo info about a user who's in the US through Google AJAX APIs, does google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region return the full state name (e.g. "California") or the abbreviation ("CA")?

If you're in the US: What result do you get for "Region" on http://www.thewhyandthehow.com/javascript-geolocation-using-google-ajax-apis/ (in the line that starts with "I’ve added one here")?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I get the abbreviation "CA" here.

Comment: That's all I needed to know. Thanks.

Comment: If "_that's all you needed to know_", then why don't you accept this answer or at least upvote it?